What is a flat measure and and how does it change the entropy of a Gaussian?
I'm reading page 6 of this paper written by David MacKay, and equation 3.2 has this funny $m^2$ which I don't understand.
Essentially, we use a second-order approximation $M^*(w)$ of an objective function $M$ parameterized by some weights $w$, and write $M^*(w) = M(w_{MP}) + \frac{1}{2}\Delta w^T A \Delta w$ (since the first order term is zero in this setup).
If we model our probability distribution as $P(w) \propto e^{-M^*(w)}$, then we can see that $P(w)$ takes the form of a Gaussian $N(\mu, \Sigma)$, with the inverse of the covariance $\Sigma^{-1} = A$ and we can plugin the entropy of a Gaussian.
However, we can see that in the text below, it states that for a flat measure $m(w) = m$, the entropy $S = \frac{k}{2}(1+ \log 2\pi) + \frac{1}{2} \log (m^2 \det A^{-1}) $.
I don't understand what a flat measure is, and how this $m^2$ came about.

